# How to read OpenJDK 7 documentation (or other -doc) packages?

Tags: command-line, java, openjdk, documentation, jdk

I have installed openjdk-7-doc but I cannot find where to read the documentations of the APIs?

E.g.: How to find/read "String class" API documentation

I prefer GUI-based over command-line but I also want to know how to read them with the command-line too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation is installed into `/usr/share/doc/PACKAGENAME`.

There are a few Documentation Viewers in Ubuntu, to help you find it. They are all web-based, though. So you need to run a local web server, and browse to their endpoints.

Off the top of my head: dhelp, dwww, and doc-central.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for the [API Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) you can use a terminal (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) to open it:

```
gnome-open /usr/share/doc/openjdk-7-jre-headless/api/index.html
```

this should open the Java API with your predefined browser. If you don't want to use a terminal, you can paste the link in any browser and make a bookmark of it:

```
file:///usr/share/doc/openjdk-7-jre-headless/api/index.html
```

Hope this helps.